# LoadRunner web_add_header() and redirects

Tags: cookies, loadrunner

First I run this from VUGen (it is built by hand):

```
Action()
{
    web_cleanup_cookies();
    web_cache_cleanup();

    web_url("entrypoint", 
            "URL=http://e34jbsl00430.devillo.com:8080/entrypoint/", 
            "TargetFrame=", 
            "Resource=0", 
            "RecContentType=text/html", 
            "Referer=",
            "Mode=HTML", 
            LAST);

    return 0;
}
```

And the page is failing to open and a sessionid is appearing in the URL. Possibly after some redirects.

When doing this manually in Firefox with FireBug turned on, I get this request/response headers:

```
Response Headers

Cache-Control   no-cache, no-store

Content-Length  0

Date    Fri, 19 Apr 2013 13:49:51 GMT

Expires Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT

Location        http://e34jbsl00430.devillo.com:8080/entrypoint/?0

Pragma  no-cache

Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1

Set-Cookie      ENTRYPOINT_JSESSIONID=WgfuCXmTF7VTCsmhWYvU-WY7; Path=/entrypoint; HttpOnly

X-Frame-Options DENY



Request Headers

Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate

Accept-Language no,en-gb;q=0.7,en;q=0.3

Connection      keep-alive

Cookie  ENTRYPOINT_JSESSIONID=DnVj0xzyLaUOKfUEFIP6bpF-

Host    e34jbsl00430.devillo.no:8080

User-Agent      Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:14.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/14.0.1
```

Then I run the same script but with `web_add_header("Cookie","ENTRYPOINT_JSESSIONID=dummy");`

And it works just fine.

Why is adding this dummy header to my script makeing this work?

Comment: If you set a different value for the 'dummy' cookie does it still work? BTW, this looks like an old question. Did you resolve your problem? If so, perhaps you could write an explanation below and accept it as the answer so that others may benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the developer of the app left a security hole for testing purposes and didn't close it after JSESSION implementation.

It looks like this session ID  "dummy" is valid always. 
Try to correlate real

> ENTRYPOINT_JSESSIONID=WgfuCXmTF7VTCsmhWYvU-WY7;

using

```
**web_reg_save_param_regexp**("ParamName=pJSESSION","RegExp=JSESSIONID=(.*?);","Ordinal=ALL",SEARCH_FILTERS, "Scope=Cookies",LAST);
```

and pass it as you did before but

```
web_add_header("Cookie","ENTRYPOINT_JSESSIONID={pJSESSION}");
```